# How to get Image to display in ASP.net app?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get a webpage to display an image on my disk, using a string from a database, the html I am using for it is thus

`<div id="userProfileImage" style="background-image: url(@Model.ProfileImage);"></div>`

The model in question would reffer to the following code,

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> DetailAsync(string id)
        {
            var user = _userService.GetById(id);
            var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);


            var model = new ProfileModel
            {
                UserId = user.Id,
                UserName = user.UserName,
                UserRating = user.Rating,
                DisplayName = user.DisplayName,
                Email = user.Email,
                ProfileImage = user.UserImage,
                MemberSince = user.MemberSince,
                IsAdmin = userRoles.Contains("Admin")
            };
            
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadProfileImage (IFormFile file)
        {
            var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
            if (UploadFile(file))
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var filePathUpload = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\images\profiles", fileName);
                var filePathDb = Path.Combine(@"\images\profiles", fileName);
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePathUpload, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
                await _userService.SetProfileImage(userId, filePathDb);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Detail", "Profile", new { id = userId });
        }
```

However, no image is displaying. When using debug, the ProfileImage field in model returns "\images\profiles\defualtProfileImage.jpg", which should point to a path in my wwwroot folder. But it's not displaying. Would anyone have any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried adding the website root to the image url? Sounds like a url mapping issue to me. You could try adding `"~/" + @Model.ProfileImage` instead

Comment: What is the resulting client-side markup for that `<div>` element?  In your browser's debugging tools, is a network request made for that image URL?  Is it the URL you expect?  What is the server's response?

Comment: IE using "wwwroot\images\profiles\defualtProfileImage.jpg"? I believe I have,, but I can try it.

Comment: @David looking in inspect element, I get the following div

<div id="userProfileImage" style="background-image: url(\images\profiles\defualtProfileImage.jpg);"></div>

which gives the same file path as the image I am looking for, but I don't know if it would look in the wwwroot folder, I'll try making that change in the brozer to see if it works

edit, it did not

Comment: @Vergil: On the network tab in the browser's debugging tools you can see every request made by the page.  One of those requests should be for that image.  There you can see the exact full URL it is requesting and what the server's response is.

Comment: @JamesS adding "~/" did not work unfortunately

Comment: @David Having checked the network tab, it is empty, so I think there is a problem with it requesting the image maybe? Not sure how to fix it though, I am rather new to programming.

Ok, I now have requests, only one is an image though, and it's not the one that I am needing to display.

Comment: @Vergil: Did you reload the page with the network tab open?  It's only "empty" if no new requests are being made.  But if *no requests are made at all* then the page isn't even being loaded in the first place.

Comment: @David yeah sorry, realised the problem and did a refresh, only got one image, but it had a string of random characters for a name, and was a blank white image.

Comment: What you want is `@Url.Content(Model.ProfileImage)` which will work even if `.PathBase` is a sub folder.

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
var filePathDb = Path.Combine(@"\images\profiles", fileName);
```

Needed to be:

```
var filePathDb = @$"/images/profiles/{fileName}"
```

The `\`s were interfering with the file name being looked for, but were correct for saving the image to the correct place on the hard drive.

Thank you contributor [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328193/david) for pointing me in the direction of the network tab of inspect element.